# getrange function is not picking up the whole row in google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to save the values from A4 to E4 in the next row, but it is picking only A4 cell and for rest it is showing empty. Please help me understand what I am missing.

```
    function saveData() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("History");
     var all_data = sheet.getRange("A4:E4").getValue();
     
      sheet.appendRow([all_data]);

  
}
```

Comment: try getValues() instead of getValue() and return to the documentation to learn why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what Cooper mentioned in the comments. Use `getValues()` since your range would return an array.

```
  function saveData() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("History");
     var all_data = sheet.getRange("A4:E4").getValues().flat();
      sheet.appendRow(all_data);

}
```

I also added the `flat()` because without this method, `all_data` would return a 2-dimensional array which `appendRow()` had some problems populating the given row.

Comment: Hi Diego, Thankyou so much for your quick response. I tried using the solution provided by you but now it is showing the error [Ljava.lang.Object;@4fb8b73c . Can you please help.

Comment: Would you be able to share the exact script you used? As well as a screenshot of your sheet that contains sample/dummy data so that we can try to isolate the problem@VandnaKhanna

Comment: I have some values in 4th row and I want them to be recorded in next row automatically at 11 pm everyday. This is the demo Sheet so you can edit my script. Note: I have used Importange function to get these Values so these may change anytime. That's why I would like to record the data once a day. Please find the link to the sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12q_83Rhuww2OjdNfp9LlGOewBUeFu_D1o6-3XK7-YbQ/edit?usp=sharing    Thanks in advance! @Diego Sanchez

Comment: @VandnaKhanna After making a copy of your demo sheet, inside Tools > Script Editor, your `saveData()` function was not yet updated to the above code. I tried updating mine using your demo sheet and everything is working fine.

Comment: I am getting the value for A4 cell only in the next row but I wanted to get the values from A4 to E4 in next cell. How can I do this? can you please help?

Comment: Can you provide me a screenshot of your code on your Script Editor page? @VandnaKhanna

Comment: Here is the link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ODD9HjYvSRdZF_tkzQEi6DpcYeryO0yN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh I see what seems to be the problem, you haven't updated your code yet to the answer I provided. You can just replace the entire `function saveData()` with the script I provided above. That should get you working

Comment: Yes I tried Solution provided by you earlier but it is showing error instead of data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-e_IVz2U2YO9s0aM-NLVdJJhoXuZj0Pv/view?usp=sharing but with my previous code it was showing the value for A4 cell only instead of whole row. Please see, I have updated my Script as per your previous solution https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VotHqcOtD-Hr5vh9F5MpJ4SNgbsUXqdd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Kindly remove the square brackets `[ ]` to make this part of the code like this. `sheet.appendRow(all_data);`

Comment: Thankyou so much! It worked. I really appreciate for your time and help :)

Comment: No problem! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you by clicking the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Comment: Hi Diego, I need your help for another query related to google sheets. Can you please help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71823006/17484517 @Diego Sanchez